# GetService in NinjectDependencyResolver not getting hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I am using a custom Dependency Resolver - NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using EssentialTools.Models;
using Ninject;

namespace EssentialTools.Infrastructure
{
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
    {
        kernel = kernelParam;
        AddBindings();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    {
        kernel.Bind<IValueCalculator>().To<LinqValueCalculator>();
    }
}
}
```

I registered the resolver in NinjectWebCommon.
And I know my AddBindings is getting hit because I can set the breakpoint and hit and inspect.
Or write debug statements to the output window.

But I don't think my GetService is getting hit.
I can't hit the break point and I can't write debug statements to the window.

I have set this up before and I have always been able to hit the breakpoint in GetServiceType(Type serviceType) and see that serviceType was the HomeController just to prove it was working.

I know its registered because AddBindings is working and if I comment it out the bind it errors.

Also if I comment out GetService it errors that I have not implemented it.  But even when implemented is not used.  It's like it's using the default.

What have I missed in the configuration?

Comment: Isn't this example from Pro ASP.NET MVC 5? I'm actually experiencing the same issue - it's magically instantiating the Controller but not hitting the GetService or GetServices method.

Comment: Yes - it is.  I've never had this happen before.  I plugged it in on my work machine several times and it happens over and over. But if I download his code and run it,it works.  I don't understand it.

Comment: This obviously an old question now, but if you are using `NinjectWebCommon` then it should work fine and you shouldn't need any of that custom code.  Just move your bindings into `NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices`  And if you absolutely *have* to use service location (like maybe in `Application_Start`) you can use `var blah = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(Blah)) as Blah;`